# Silverlight: Right and left justify elements in a ItemTemplate?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have the following ItemTemplate:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Topics}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FallbackValue='topic name', Converter={StaticResource topicToStrConverter}}" 
                               Margin="10,0"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Image Source="Images/appbar.cancel.rest.png" />
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I would like to right-align all of the buttons regardless of the length of their corresponding text, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I'm using Silverlight 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your panel doesn't have a set length, so there's nothing to define where you want the right edge to be.  If you put the items into a StackPanel or Grid with a fixed Width, you'll see the behavior you expect.

Comment: How do I define the length to be as long as widest text element?

Comment: @Rosarch You could create a property to bind to the width and then examine the ActualLength properties of all of the text blocks in your list every time a new object is added.  But I think this would end up looking weird.  I'd suggest you choose a maximum width for the text you want to support (perhaps allow wrapping if necessary) or choose a maximum width for the ItemsControl itself and work backwards from there, based on any other elements you want to include (scrollbars, etc).  That way your buttons are always in a consistent place and your UI looks more stable.